# SocketIO: When to use io and whn to use socket?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am learning node and socket io. I have been watching tutorials, at first it is good, but then, they start to mix up using `socket.on(), socket.emit()` and `io.on(), io.emit()`. It seems very confusing. Can anyone clear my concept that where to use `io` and where to use `socket` in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically think of `io` as the top level socket.io engine manager.  If you want to do something at the top level that either creates some sort of resource like a `socket` or a new namespace object or sends a message to all existing connections in a namespace, then you use `io`.

Once you create a resource like a socket, you then use that object itself to operate on it.

On the server, you use `io` when you want to listen for new connections or when you want to broadcast to all connections.  There are a few other things you can also do with it.

In the client, you use `io` when you want to connect to a server.

You use `socket` when you want to communicate with one particular connection as that connection is represented by the `socket` object.  So, each client connection has a `socket` object and you send or receive info to/from that client by using methods on the `socket` object.

So, `const socket = io.connect(url)` or as a shortcut `const socket = io(url)` will connect a client to a server and give you the client-side `socket` object.

`io.on('connection, socket => { ... })` will listen for an incoming client connection on the server and give you the `socket` for that new connection.

`socket.emit()` sends a message to the other end of that particular socket (whether on client or server).

`io.emit()` on the server sends a messages to all current connected clients (technically all clients connected to the top level `io` namespace - there can be other namespaces).

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining in such detail.